# Deactivate Toggle Buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Very simple I just need a quick pointer,

Bootstrap Button Group (for a 1-in-3 toggle button) defined as:

```
    <!--  Twitter Bootstrap Button Group -->
     <div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">General</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 3</button>
    </div>
```

On clicking a button I select it to keep it active/pressed: that's my current tab, **but I need to unselect all others. Only 1 toggle button at a time.**

```
   $('.btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('active');
    })
// this never unselects other toggle buttons
```

Also, how would I define the content under each toggle button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove `active` class from previous `button`(which was selected previous) using `removeClass()` method.

```
 $('.btn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('.btn-group > button.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
 })
```

```js
$('.btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.btn-group > button.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">General</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 3</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Just had a thought... This might remove `active` classes from any other buttons outside the scope of the current group? Could it possibly be safer to only remove active class from the `siblings` of the current button?

Comment: Dear Sir, Thank you for considering the concern raised. Though there's just one small issue that I'd like to address and I'm not entirely sure if it should be considered under or beyond the realms of the question asked. I wouldn't also feel good in trying to sound pedantic in the comments section of a wonderful answer here. So, with sincere respect to your post, I shall create one new post, referencing yours, if that's not an issue... Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Additionally to @Alexandru-IonutMihai answer, if you want to do it one line you could select the active button and the just-clicked button and [toggle their classes](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/).

```js
var $btn = $('.btn-group .btn');

$btn.click(function(e) {

  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).add($btn.filter('.active')).toggleClass('active');

})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="btn-group">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">General</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 2</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 3</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">General</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 2</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 3</button>
</div>

<div class="btn-group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 4</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 5</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Tab 6</button>
</div>
```

Just adding one small tweak to Alexandru's original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41915089/2298301)...

In case there were multiple button groups within the page, then to isolate the select / deselect events, and to ascertain that those button groups don't interfere with each other, we could modify the code slightly as follows:

```
$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');
   $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

The only new line added here is: `$(this).siblings().removeClass('active')` such that it removes any of the previously added `active` class from the current button group only.